# Solving limits of a sine wave $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

So I got this assignment. And I was wondering how is it possible to get a limit from a constantly changing formula. 
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
Can I only look in the domain $]0,2\pi[$?

Comment: Hint: $|\sin x|\le1$.

Comment: At infinity the function oscillates and thus no distinct solution

Comment: oh yes offcourse. Since a sinewave can't be bigger than 1 the limit will be (in the most optimistic case):$$\frac{1}{\infty}=0$$
Thanks @DavidMitra

Comment: @Socre:  Your analysis is not well-founded.

Comment: @Socre Nope my friend. I just answered my own question thx to David here. somethimes the answer is so obvious i just miss it.

Comment: @RubenDefour can use l hospital's rule. Using it we have $lim_{x->\infty}cos(x)$. What will this limit be?

Comment: @Socre: I'm pretty sure that de l'Hospital is not applicable in this case...

Comment: @Socre L'Hopital's rule only applies when both numerator and denominator go to infinity or both go to 0. That doesn't happen here. Plus, if you just plot this function, it's obvious what happens.

Comment: @Fabian you are right, you do not use the l hospitals rule, that was my mistake

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368086/evaluating-and-proving-lim-x-to-infty-frac-sin-xx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to take help of the following:

1. $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$$
2. $$-1\le\sin x\le1$$

Comment: This is wrong because $\sin x$ does not approach "a finite rational number" as $x\to \infty$.

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot only analyze the problem within $]0, 2\pi[$, although $\sin$ is periodic.

Yes, the limit exists and $=0$. We have $x > 0$ only if 
$$
\bigg| \frac{\sin x}{x} \bigg| \leq \frac{1}{x};
$$
given any $\varepsilon > 0$,
we have $1/x < \varepsilon$ if $x > 1/\varepsilon$;
hence we have proved this: for every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $x > 1/\varepsilon$ only if 
$$
\bigg| \frac{\sin x}{x} \bigg| < \varepsilon;
$$
that is, 
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can't look only in $]0,2\pi]$, as this function is not periodic. The shortest way is to observe that  $\biggl|\dfrac{\sin x}x\biggr|\le\biggl|\mkern2mu\dfrac1x\mkern2mu\biggr|$, which tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Most beginning calc students don't know big O notation, but they know the Squeeze Theorem...

Comment: Maybe he/she'll have the curiosity to delve into asymptotic analysis seeing how efficient and short it is on simple cases. I agree on this example, the Squeeze theorem is just as good.

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$-1\leq\sin x\leq 1$$
$$-\frac1{|x|}\leq\frac{\sin x}{|x|}\leq \frac1{|x|}$$
Using the squeeze theorem, we have
$$-\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac1{|x|}\leq\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin x}{|x|}\leq\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac1{|x|}$$
As $x\to\infty$, we have $|x|=x$. So we can drop the absolute value bars
$$-\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac1{x}\leq\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}\leq\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac1{x}$$
$$0\leq\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}\leq 0$$
Therefore
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} =0$$